# i want to call the controller by Ajax call butt how can i use JQUERY-UNOBTRUSIVE not using form tag

Tags: asp.net-core

we can call the controller easily by using form tag like

```
 <form asp-action="PartialAction" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax- 
        update="#ProductList">
     <input type="text" name="name" /><input type="submit" />
   </form>
```

now i want to call action by using ajax. how can we use data-ajax , data-ajax-mode and data-ajax-updata attribute use in ajax call

```
var Categories = function (Key,Length) {
          
            $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/ShopGrid/PartialAction",
                    data: { GrpKey: array },
                    
                    success: function (response) {

                    }
                })
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect of `data-ajax`,`data-ajax-mode` and `data-ajax-update` euqals to using `.html()` method in ajax success function:

```
success: function (response) {
    $("#ProductList").html(response);
}
```

You can check the `jquery-unobtrusive-ajax.js` source code here:

https://github.com/aspnet/jquery-ajax-unobtrusive/blob/main/src/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js#L55

Comment: sorry my question is how we can use data-ajax  data-ajax-mode data-ajax-update

Comment: Sorry,If you use ajax, no need use `data-ajax-mode` and `data-ajax-update` again.

Comment: the effect of `data-ajax-mode` and `data-ajax-update` is equal to `$("#ProductList").html(response)`.

Comment: I have updated the source code for further explanation.

Comment: Hi Rena yes your answer helpful for me thanks lot of you.

Comment: when i cast vote message will show my reputation is less than 15 so i cannot cast vote

Comment: Hi @mubashir, can you click the √ to accept my answer now?

Comment: Ok got it i have accept your answer